# I am using image_picker to get image from gallery and camera but size is to small

Tags: image, flutter, dart, upload

Here the image is clear:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpLaN.jpg)

Here it is not clear?(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZVOw.jpg)

The problem is:

By the first picture i get the image from firebase Storage directly.

By the second picture i get the link (firebase Storage) from Firestore and display it with a networkImage:

```
 child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                            pic,
                            scale: 1,
                          ),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover)
                      )),
```

And then the image is low quality.
How can i fix this?

Comment: To get maximum image quality remove `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` properties of `pickImage`. You can also remove `imageQuality` since 100 is the default.

Comment: @Jens  Image stays still small, i used an image from instagram so it is a square image but image is small in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the MediaQuery.size doesn't use the same measure as the photos in the image picker. Try to remove the maxWidth and maxHeight parameters.

Comment: if i use the link from Firebase storage so, it gives good quality, but when i try to get it from firebase with code, it is bad quality